# Searching on relationship using GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I’m trying to set up a GraphQL server using Node, Sequelize and mySQL. I’ve done some work with REST API’s in the past but am new to GraphQL so have limited experience and am concerned about accidentally adopting poor practices.

I have three tables: events, event_days and attendees. An event has many days and an event also has many attendees. I have set up the schema so that I can query and get a list of events and their associated days and attendees. For example:

```
{
  events {
    name,
    venue,
    attendees {
      name
    }
    days {
      date,
      start_time
    }
  }
}
```

I can also add an ‘id’ parameter to the ‘events’ line to return a specific event. All pretty straightforward. What I would like to be able to do though is run a query to find all events on a certain day or attended by people called ‘John’, etc. If I add the parameters after the ‘days’ field name (as per example below) or ‘attendees’ field name then the query fails saying that these aren’t accepted parameters. In some ways this seems most logical as it is attaching the parameter on the relationship as opposed to the root query but it repeatedly fails despite the various different ways I tried so I wondered if parameters are ONLY supposed to be attached to the ‘events’ line of the query and the other field names are JUST for what is to be returned? Is this even the ‘right’ place to put these parameters in terms of good practice (or even possible)? Part of the reason for trying to implement it like this is that I was wondering if Sequelize (or some middleware) can interpret which field the query is attached to and then build the query based on that.

```
{
  events {
    name,
    venue,
    attendees {
      name
    }
    days ( date: ’2017-07-24' ) {
      date,
      start_time
    }
  }
}
```

I came up with two alternatives but am not sure which is the right way to go in terms of good practice. When I was creating a REST API I found plenty of guidelines for good practice but these don’t seem as available with GraphQL.

**Alternative Method 1**: Have several available parameters set up (id, date, attendee, etc) that don’t necessarily query the event table itself but one of the related tables also and then interpret these parameters and build a query on the server side. This seems a good way of doing it but also that it could get out of hand quite quickly if I needed to set up quite different searches depending on the parameters passed.

```
{
  events ( date: ’2017-07-24' ) {
    name,
    venue,
    attendees {
      name
    }
    days {
      date,
      start_time
    }
  }
}
```

**Alternative Method 2**: Have a sub-query under events that is specifically designed to carry out searches on that relationship

```
{
  events {
    searchByDate (date: ‘2017-07-24') {
      name,
      venue,
      attendees {
        name
      }
      days {
        date,
        start_time
      }
    }
    findAll {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```